# making a RC4 algorithm, problems with the KSA(key scheduling algorithm)

Tags: python, rfc

this is my code:

```
def KSA(key):
    key_length = len(key)
    S = list(range(256))
    j = 0
    for i in range(0,255):
        j = (j + S[i] + key[i % key_length]) & 256
        print(S[i],S[j])
        S[i] , S[j] = S[j] , S[i]  # Swapping
    return S
```

getting list index out of range when used with key = [5]. and i don't know why.

Comment: The error is due to the `j`'s value when it exceeds `[0...255]` range and would occur with `key=2` also :)

Comment: how do i fix it??

Comment: A Very good explanation and implementation are [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-rc4-algorithm/)!

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code. You used & instead of % for modulo 256, you got it right for the key length part though.  AND you should also use range(256) instead of range(0, 255) as that will only go as high as index 254 (that argument is actually the RANGE not the explicit stopping point).